# Unable to run Grid Autosport: "cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory"

Tags: 16.04, steam, libraries

When I attempt to run GRID: Autosport from Steam, GridAutosport appears in Task Manager, but nothing seems to happen, and 0% CPU is used by that process. When I attempt to run the executable from the terminal emulator, like this:

```
thisisntmyrealusername@thisisntmyrealcomputer:~$ cd "/home/thisisntmyrealusername/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/GRID Autosport/bin"

thisisntmyrealusername@thisisntmyrealcomputer:~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/GRID Autosport/bin$ ./GridAutosport
```

I get this:

```
./GridAutosport: error while loading shared libraries: librtmp.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried reinstalling librtmp1 with Synaptic, but that did not rectify the issue.